# Qt mainwindow transparency background

Tags: qt, widget, alpha-transparency, qmainwindow

I want to use a png image with transparency and custom border in Qt mainwindow background like this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [shiaupload.ir](http://www.shiaupload.ir/images/77810787432153420049.png))</sub>

is there any good idea?

Comment: [QWidget::setMask(const QBitmap &bitmap)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setMask) and [QPixmap::mask()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html#mask) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You can also do something like `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`
`this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` and then paint your background.

Comment: @thuga - your last post is an answer. I want to add, that if Qt4 is used - there is a bug with minimizing and restoring window: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Then paint the background of your window in the [paint event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

Note: As pointed out by Dmitry, in Qt4 there is a [bug with minimizing and restoring the window](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17548).

Another option is to use [QWidget::setMask(const QBitmap & bitmap)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setMask), but this could be slow if the region is complex.

Comment: Hi, can you point out how achieve the transparency through setting mask?

Comment: @Cupidvogel Is the example in the documentation insufficient?

Comment: No, it is not working. I tried to apply that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372291/qt-render-qframe-with-image-as-background-without-using-wa-translucentbackgrou, I could not make it work.

Comment: @Cupidvogel Try it on an empty project with just a main window nothing else.